# Update Database-Context in Android when Activity changes?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

dD I need to update the Context when I access a database with multiple Activities?

My App works like this: `Activities <=> DataSource <=> DBHelper`

My DataSource has the methods open and close which retrieve or release the database from the DBHelper.

The Activities call `open()` on the DataSource in `onCreate()` and `onResume()` and `close()` in `onPause()`. Do I need to pass the context of the Activity and create a new DataBase like this:

```
public void open(Context context) {
    if(!context.equals(this.context)) 
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

or is it not necessary?

Comment: im wondering because i dont understand the use of context completely. The App doesnt work yet so i cant test it right now.

Comment: No, you don't have to.

Answer (score -5):

@Hoan Nguyen wrote:

> No, you don't have to.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)